# How to explore set of nonnegative vectors consistent with a set of projections?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to infer an unknown vector `x` in a high-dimensional space (thousands of dimensions), and have good measurements of its projections onto a few (15) directions -- i.e. if the columns of `v[i,j]` form a basis for the space, I know `v[,j]*x = v[1,j]*x[1]+...+v[n,j]*x[n]` for `1<=j<=15`, with a good idea of the error.

I also know that `x[i]>=0` for all `i`.  I would like some way to find nonnegative estimates of `x` with projections close to the observed values.

I have tried using least-squares minimization with linear constraints, (optimizing a quadratic objective with linear constraints, using the `quadprog` package in R). However, the result is not as close to the observed projetions as they should be, based on my knowledge of the observation error.  I would like to assess if this is because there does not exist a better solution, or if the algorithm failed to find it for numerical reasons.

What is a good method for doing this sort of thing?  Or, are there tricks for doing convex optimization in high-dimensional space?

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of linear equality constraints of the form

```
a_i * x = b_i
```

And a set of positivity constraints

```
x >= 0
```

Or, in matrix form

```
A x = b
x >= 0
```

All this tells us for now is that your target vector is in a [Convex Polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polyhedron) but that is not much. Now we have to decide what to do.

**If all you need to find a feasible point** you can do so by running [Phase 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Finding_an_initial_canonical_tableau) of the [Simplex algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm). Thousands of dimensions should not be a big problem since linear programming is really fast and should handle that kind of input. You can choose your favorite linear optimization solver[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.coin-or.org/projects/Clp.xml)[<sup>2</sup>](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lpsolve/) here.

**If you also want to find an optimal feasible point** and the objective function is **linear** then you also don't have to do anything. Just take the same solver that you would use to determine feasibility and tell it to also optimize as well - the amount of work to do is basically the same.

**If you also want to find an optimal feasible point** and the objective function is **non linear** then things get a little more complicated and you have more things to choose from. Quadratic objective functions are a common special case so there are specific solvers for that but otherwise you start getting lots of stuff to choose from.

Comment: clarified original post a bit.  The constraints are not equality, actually -- the observation error means they are best formulated as quadratic, `\sum (a_i * x - b_i)^2 < C`.  btw, `quadprog` avoids finding a feasible point by working on the dual problem, where this is trivial.

Comment: Nonlinear contraints are finicky. Have you tried to see what kind of results you can get by using equality instead? (you don't even need to be *too* strict if you don't want to - you can add some extra variables to soften up the constrains somewhat if you need to)

Answer (score 0):

So, if I am understanding correctly, you are given `xp`, a projection of a vector `x` onto a subspace `P` which is defined by a set of basis vectors `{p[i]}`. You want to find **some** non-negative vector that projects there. The problem is trivial if you omit the non-negative condition---just pick your projected vector:

```
x = sum(xp[i]*p[i])
```

Just to clarify, the length of `xp` is the dimension of the subspace `P` and is equal to the number of rows in p. The length of each p[i] is equal to the dimension of the original high-dimensional space (it's what makes them basis vectors).

The fact that you are not doing the above tells me that the projection is **not** non-negative, so you need to add some vector orthogonal to `P` to get the result you want. The problem is, you don't really know if such a vector exists. For example, imagine the original space is the plane and `P` is the line `alpha*(1,1)`. If you have a negative projection `(-1,-1)` then, no matter what vector of the form `a*(1,-1)` you add, you won't be able to get a positive result. The same applies for any dimension and any projection that is negative in more than one basis (I am assuming your bases are orthogonal. If they are not, things get a little bit more hairy).

So, to summarize, look at what your projected vector looks like in the full dimensional space and if you find more than one negative entry you are pretty much hosed when it comes to finding a non-negative embedding of the projection into the full dimensional space.